# Azure Functions .NET 5 SignalR Group Output

Tags: c#, .net, azure, function, serverless

I am using Azure Functions and SignalR to create a chat application, but for some reason I cannot get the group ID output to work. I can notify groups using the ID easily on my server, so I know that the clients are in the right groups. Also, I can notify clients individually using UserId in the output class, so I know the functions are working.

```
        [SignalROutput(HubName = nameof(EventHub))]
        public async Task<SignalRMessage> Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent input, FunctionContext context)
        {

         ...

            return new SignalRMessage
            {
                GroupName = chat.Id.ToString(),
                Target = "newMessage",
                Arguments = new object[]
                        {
                            new { message }
                        }
            };

        }
```

Does anything look wrong with this code, assuming all external things are correct? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i can answer more precisely to reach your requirement ,

Basically ,`SignalR` Service allows users to be [add/ Remove to groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=csharp#group-management). Then message can be sent to a group. You can use the `SignalR` output binding to manage the user's group membership.

Please refer the below links for more information:

.[Azure function binding for Signal IR service.| Git-Hub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension) .

. [Manage users Groups in Signal IR | MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0) .